# GooglePlayServices not working

Tags: android

I am currently trying to get GooglePlayServices working, but I have no idea why it doesn't. In the manifest there is the permission in the application context:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

However, every time I try to check if GooglePlayServices is connected, it returns a false and below is the message in the logcat:

```
I/dalvikvm(8477): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzh 
    W/dalvikvm(8477): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 612: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller; 
    D/dalvikvm(8477): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
```

The target properties of GPS is 4.4.2.

If you have more questions just comment.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a bug described here:

[Issue 91424:   Bug introduced with 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=91424)

**update the support library to 22.1.0 or later!**